# Suppressing Powershell Errors When Calling External Executables

Tags: powershell, error-handling, executable, powershell-cmdlet

I have a PowerShell script that is calling an external executable and I want to suppress any error that comes from it. How can this be achieved. With PowerShell cmdlets, I can use the standard `-ErrorAction` argument to `SilentlyContinue`, however this is an external executable:

```
someExe --argument
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error output of external commands goes to the [error stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) (provided the command is writing error messages to STDERR), so you just need to [redirect](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) that stream to suppress the message:

```
someExe --argument 2>$null
```

If the command writes to STDOUT instead of STDERR (unusual behavior, but not unheard of) you may need to redirect the success output stream instead:

```
someExe --argument >$null
```

Comment: You can read more on this from [about_redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)

Comment: Windows' own `sc.exe` throws error to STDOUT